# php clear or renew session when it reaches memory limit

Tags: php, session

Our users have started to complain when they have been logged in for a while and it starts to slow down, making the site unusable.

This happens after a few hours (they are logged in and making tasks all day) so they have to log in and out. Easy done, but not if it has to be done several times a day. What would be a good solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the root cause of the slowdowns, you might consider the following issues:

- low memory limit
- database not optimized
- too many opened sessions
- poorly written code
- front end part of your application is doing heavy javascript calculations

After you will find the slow pieces of your application first try to improve it. What is your memory limit and can you not increase it ?

Comment: Do you know any good tools, classes or libraries which will make the task a little more efficient, like when they are saying "the site is really slow now" I can just check log files or something?

Comment: You have to do some performance measurement, one way would be to use [Xdebug Profiling Tool](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). Here is the sample tutorial how to do it, also a very good tool to view your results from xdebug profiling is [Webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/webgrind) or [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html). You can view which parts of your code are exceptionally slow.